# Spring cloud config -Custom location of jce jar files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

For reasons outside my control, I am not allowed to edit the Jre and add the two jce jars to it. Is there anyway I can tell my config server when it starts up that the location of those two jar files is in a custom location? 
I have tried the following option-
Added it in the root of application directory.

But. Spring is not able to pick it up.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. This is not a config server problem, but a JRE problem. Later version of the JRE ship with JCE policy files and later even still it's enabled by default https://golb.hplar.ch/p/JCE-policy-changes-in-Java-SE-8u151-and-8u152

Comment: Lol wish I could update the jdk itself. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a JRE problem (you need to copy the two jce jars to JRE security library. The Oracle website already described the procedure. However, I guess the question was asking, how to do so to the embedded tomcat within a spring boot application.

Read [this post](https://softwarecave.org/2014/06/14/adding-external-jars-into-maven-project/) for further informations.